# PYCOM FiPy does not attach to the Cellular Network - LTE Italy

Tags: micropython, lte, pycom

I have tried to connect to the internet using LTE but the network won't attach.
I want to determine the proper carrier on my Fipy, I did not get any response, the list was empty.

The comand AT+CEREG?' response OK.

The firmware version that I have is LR5.1.1.0-47510

Does someone have any idea on how I could manage to attach to the network? Any previous experiences Thank you in advance.

```
`>>> from network import LTE
>>> lte=LTE()
>>> lte.send_at_cmd("AT+SQNCTM=?")
''
>>>
```

I have been running all variations of the default test program with any success

```
from network import LTE
import time
import socket

lte = LTE()
lte.attach()
print("attaching..",end='')
while not lte.isattached():
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print('.',end='')
    print(lte.send_at_cmd('AT!="fsm"'))         # get the System FSM
print("attached!")

lte.connect()
print("connecting [##",end='')
while not lte.isconnected():
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print('#',end='')
    #print(lte.send_at_cmd('AT!="showphy"'))
    print(lte.send_at_cmd('AT!="fsm"'))
print("] connected!")
```

Comment: The [fipy] tag is for the FiPy partial differential equation solver, not communications widget

Comment: @jeguyer What do you mean by this? FiPy board suppose to provide 5 types of communication, in fact, we were able to use it with LoRa and Wi-Fi, but we need LTE to be able to send the data where there is no Wi-Fi coverage.

Comment: I mean that the [fipy] tag on Stack Overflow is about about a piece of software called [FiPy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy), not about the communications boards from [Pycom](https://pycom.io/?s=fipy). I know because I created the tag and our software used the name for years before Pycom did.

Comment: ok, thanks, the tag has been removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my findings are correct, you need to factory-reset the modem first!

You can do this by sending the corresponding AT-command like this:
`lte.send_at_cmd('AT+SQNSFACTORYRESET=?')`

After this you need to reboot the device to complete the reset process!

The device should now attach to the network without issues.

PS: I know, Pycom offers a method `.factory_reset()` in its LTE-class, but it seems like it just crashes whenever used.

Also, see [my answer in the Pycom forum](https://forum.pycom.io/post/41483)